# Safe code execution on server side API with Roslyn

Tags: c#, security, roslyn, code-injection, roslyn-code-analysis

To give my users more flexibility and to let them write their own expressions, I want to allow them to write very simple C# statements in a text field that are executed on server side to do some custom calculations.
I am archiving this with Roslyn.
A good example to start for me can be found [here](https://github.com/joelmartinez/dotnet-core-roslyn-sample/blob/master/Program.cs).

I let users inject code inside an evaluation function, like this:

```
        string codeToCompile = @"
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        namespace Evaluator
        {
            public class Evaluator
            {
                public string Eval()
                {
                    " + {POTENTIALLY_DANGEROUS_CODE_GOES_HERE} + @"                      
                }
            }
        }";
```

You can see that the injected code is *always* inside an Eval-Function and should return a string in the end.
The user can decide how this string is calculated.
I am now thinking of security, because I do not have any control of the injected code.

Actually my users should only be able to:

- Use mathematical expressions
- Primitive variables
- if statements

So an example injected code could look like this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

if(a < b) 
{
   return "a is smaller";
}
else
{
   return "a is bigger or equal";
}
```

You can see in the sample code above, that the namespace is limited to "System" and  "System.Collections.Generic", so a lot of stuff wont be possible anymore (like reading something from the file system of the server and outputting this information as a string)

I also replace all occurences of loops, so expressions like *while, for, foreach* etc... are removed from the string.

But I am still pretty unsure if this solution is secure.

1. What could a potential attacker still do now? (Especially with the options of the two provided namespaces)
2. Is there any best-practice what I could do in this case, to prevent attacks?

Comment: This link would help you to implement infrastructure to execute safe code on server.          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231392/how-to-make-safe-online-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, this is *very* hard to get right. Very hard. "If you have to ask how to do it you might be over your head" hard. Some fun things to consider:

1. Just because you limit the namespaces at the top of the file doesn't mean somebody can't explicitly qualify to something in their code snippet to a different namespace. So what's important is you have to walk the entire code to see if there's uses of any other types. I can't tell if your explicit list of things you're allowing implicitly disallows all method calls or object creation.
2. Be careful with assuming anything in System is safe. Consider System.Activator, which lets you call CreateInstance and pass in the string name of another type to create it. That type alone lets you bypass any other checks you might do. And that was just the first one that jumped out when I pulled up the docs in the System namespace alphabetically!
3. ...and of course don't just block System.Activator specifically. Any time you update which framework people are writing code against, there might be new types that are problematic.

Also consider your types of potential security attacks: even if you can't write files, can you still leak information from your server (like the username or machine name) that might  allow the user to break into your system some other way. Or they just write an infinite loop which consumes server resources. You mentioned that you'll remove loops, but don't forget things like goto, or just writing some sort of recursive function that does a stack overflow.

I'm not going to say "just do X and it's safe", because I don't even trust myself to write that. But:

1. Use your OS to help you isolate: run this in a separate process with less or no permissions, etc. If you can do a separate VM/container, great. The more you can isolate here the better.
2. If you're going to do code inspection, don't reject patterns that you know are bad; instead write code that only accepts patterns that you know are "safe". And that might result in a lot of work to opt in silly things, but the alternative requires you to enumerate all that is bad.

Comment: Thanks! I already expected it would be hard to archive a safe approach. What I did now is creating a whitelist of "allowed terms". The code can only contain terms from this list. Everything else will stop validation. What do you think about that: var whiteList = new List<string> {"if","{","}",";","\\","+","-","*","/","\"","<","(",")",">","=","return","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","null","ToString","int","long","double","float","char","string","else",".","var","new","DateTime","Parse","AddDays","ToUniversalTime","Date",":"}; Now a user is VERY limited in his options...

Comment: Ah man... inline functions could still be recursive. But thats the only issue I find here... maybe I remove {} from the list...

Comment: Even that's enough to crash a process with out of memory, if you do something like ```string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = s1 + s1;
string s3 = s2 + s2;
string s4 = s3 + s3;
string s5 = s4 + s4;```
long enough until eventually the strings being allocated are gigabytes in size which can easily crash your process (or something else on the machine.)

Comment: I limited the maximum length of the code to 300 characters - also I am running it inside a seperate task. If the task takes longer than 5 seconds, its canceled. So I also avoid all kinds of loops/recursions now. Any other ideas, what could be done? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not need C# code? There are multiple options to integrate a script language. They will be interpreted and slower but that is usually not an issue.

I can recommend https://github.com/sebastienros/jint for JavaScript for example. (I'm not affiliated with the project) It has good interoparability with the hosting C# code.  It also has built-in safety guards for "resource" attacks like endless loops or excessive memory consumption.

Small word of caution: Be careful what kind of .net interoparability you allow or you might open up a security risk even with interpreted code.